# Do .NET Environment Variables get deleted

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to store my AWS Access Keys somewhere private, and read via code, not stored in it. I'm thinking on storing them in [EnviromentVariabels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), but from the description, it makes it unclear if they are only kept until the application is restarted, or stored in registry until over written.

`Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored in the current process`

and

`Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored in the current process or in the Windows operating system registry key reserved for the current user or local machine.`

Are they kept for good, or even is there a better way of saving them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables that are created for the current process indeed cease to exist when the process ends. Environment variables that are stored in the registry for the current user or the matchine, however, will remain there until explicitly removed.

Use the [overload of `SetEnvironmentVariable` that takes an `EnvironmentVariableTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/96xafkes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to determine where your variable is going to be saved. The [documentation on `EnvironmentVariableTarget`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.environmentvariabletarget%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains thoroughly under what circumstances the stored values are kept or discarded:

- `Process`: "When the process terminates, the operating system destroys the environment variable in that process."
- `Machine`/`User`: "When the process terminates, the operating system destroys the environment variable in that process. However, the environment variable in the registry persists until the user removes it programmatically or by means of an operating system tool."

---

That said, I am not convinced an environment variable is a suitable placed to store any access kinds that are supposed to be kept private. Environment variables can be read and written to by any application on the system, and they are even quite an exposed place (as opposed to anywhere buried in the registry or the file system) as they [an be directly enumerated with the `Environment` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.environment.getenvironmentvariables%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Each process on windows gets its own copy of the environment variables, and they're all gone after the process terminates. However, you can modify the external environment in some ways, some of them are explained a few clicks away from the link you've provided: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.environmentvariabletarget%28v=vs.90%29.aspx